# Prompt Page Requires Entry, Required set to No

Tags: cognos

I have a report that I developed that utilizes render variables as described [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/cognos/reporting/dynamic_report_design/page570.html).

My prompt page has 3 check box groups filled with variables. My first box is set to required, as it contains key information that needs to be pulled. The 2nd and 3rd have optional values. When the report runs, it requires at least one of the options in box 2 and 3 to be selected.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a parameter is referenced directly in a query data item, Cognos will force it's associated prompt to be required even if you set it to 'Optional'. If this is the issue, the solution is to use a prompt macro instead of the normal ?? syntax. You set a default value to pass if the prompt isn't satisfied. This allows the prompt to act like an optional prompt.

The minimum syntax is:

```
#prompt('prompt_name','string','')#
```

The third parameter is the default value. I have just used an empty string here but you could change this to whatever you want.

Comment: So I have the following written as the expression in the data item referenced in check box group 2    ''case when ('C28' in (#promptmany('Field Box 2','varchar')#))
then([SQL1].[Address Line 3])
else null     *** Would I need to simplly add ,'' after the varchar?
end''   @Johnsonium

Comment: And if so, would that change need to be made to every date item in check box group 2 and 3?

Comment: Yes. You need to add a default value which would be a third parameter in your promptmany() function. Since you are using 'in' you would have to repeat the prompt macro for every test in the case statement. If you were doing a simple single comparison then you could use the simple case syntax which would only require the function be defined once.

Comment: I change the expression for each data item in Field Box 2 to the following expression - case when ('C54' in (#promptmany('Field Box 2','varchar','')#))
then([SQL1].[columnanme])
else null  and it still requires a box to be selected within that field box in order to continue.
end